# Commas with quotes

Tags: orthography, commas, quotations, citation, style-manuals

I read the following sentence<sup>1</sup>:

> He rallied the Senate with the plea**,** “It’s time to change the Senate before this institution becomes obsolete.”

I’m wondering whether a comma should be placed after *plea*, before the quotation that follows.

This question is not a duplicate.

---

1. Originally uttered by Senator Harry Reid, U.S. Senate Majority Leader, as reported by the Associated Press in many newspapers on November 13<sup>th</sup>, 2013.

Comment: This looks like straightforward quote punctuation.  Why should this not be considered a duplicate or even general reference?  What am I missing here?

Comment: I guess it's not. Usually, quotes are introduced with a verb. As in `he said, "...`, whereas this is the DO is `plea` and I don't even know what the quote is.

Comment: Certainly "the plea" is not a quotative verb, suggesting the comma should/could be deleted, but reading it as "with the plea 'It's time to change...'" does not sound right. The comma used in the example is stylistic in that it makes the sentence read better, but it really seems to be standing in for "that": "He rallied the Senate with the plea that 'It's time to change...'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, but not always, there is a comma before a quote, as you have indicated. However, it's a matter of style and not a rule.

[Grammar Monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/quotation_%28speech%29_marks_colon_or_comma.htm) advocates for the comma before the quote, but issues this tip:

> **IT'S NOT A HARD AND FAST RULE:
>
> The majority of people do not adhere to the guidelines regarding the use of commas and colons with quotations. Nowadays, it is acceptable to introduce a quotation with a comma, a colon or nothing. In modern writing, the choice of punctuation depends largely on the desired flow of the text (i.e., how much the writer wants the reader to pause).

[Perdue Online](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/577/01/), [AP guide](http://www.grammaruntied.com/punctuation/comma.html), and [Grammar Book](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/quotes.asp) are in favor of the comma before the quote.

I wish I could tell you which do **not** require it, (I believe Grammar Girl and others do not) but I can't dig them up just this moment.

Comment: I guess I'm totally old-school then because I haven't heard of the no-comma trend.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - I hadn't either before I joined this site. :)

Comment: Grammar Monster does/do not advocate very strongly for the comma: << HOT TIP: IT'S NOT A HARD AND FAST RULE

The majority of people do not adhere to the guidelines regarding the use of commas and colons with quotations. Nowadays, it is acceptable to introduce a quotation with a comma, a colon or nothing.>>

Comment: And Grammar Monster supports the use of commas that solely indicate pauses. I think most cases of using a comma to indicate a pause, or in any other stylistic sense, is actually informed by and informs the syntax (in the sense that the pause itself does this). If it didn't we would, have all sorts, of strange comma usage.

Comment: @nxx But I've referred elsewhere to articles endorsing using commas to help readability, from both a garden-path-structure-avoiding perspective and from a fainting-through-lack-of-breathing-opportunities perspective. These articles agree that the usages they readily espouse aren't grammatically required.

Comment: I agree that they aren't grammatically required in such cases, but I believe they are still syntactically and not **only** stylistically beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with most of what has been said, except, if you plan to submit any writing for publication, I suggest you use the comma, and use it before the quotation marks to introduce a quote. If the comma was not in the quoted sentence, do not put it in because it would be altering a quote. This is what editors expect, and may disqualify a work if commas are used incorrectly throughout a piece of writing. If it is for a college paper, definitely use the comma where you found it above, not any other form unless instructed by the professor.